# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Data not being saved to database table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have suddenly hit a problem from my ASP.Net application where the data being passed to the stored procedure which contains an insert statement is not being committed to the database. No error is being thrown up from the database to the web application, and it appears from the web application that data is being saved to the table.

To try and resolve it placed a begin transaction before the insert statement, and commit transaction at the end, but this has had no effect.

Does anyone know what is going wrong? I has only just started happening, and before there was no problem and data was being saved.

Comment: Have you checked the stored procedure ?

Comment: Run a SQL Server trace, look at the stored procedure executed (parameters etc) and run it in the management studio window independently.

Comment: I have checked the stored procedure and as I said it was fine before.

Comment: How and where do I find SQL Server trace in Management Studio

Comment: Use [profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181091.aspx) to monitor the stored procedure as it executes to see if there are any errors shown.

Comment: I have got SQL Profile working and I am looking at the trace, but I do not entirely understand what is showing me. I can see the beginning of the execution of the stored proc and the values being entered, and it steping through the code hitting the try, catch and completing the stored procedure. What I don't is the commit transaction in the code, but apart from that it looks ok, but no data in the table, though. Still confused!

Comment: We could help a whole lot more if you would show us the code in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found problem. Mismatch on datatypes in table on one column. Funny thing that no error was being thrown by SQL Server 2008, though!

Comment: It probably was throwing an error, but not being handled correctly in the CATCH block.

Comment: or else it was throwing a compile error and never actually executing.